# How to get the Domain of Current User programmatically in Store Apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

We developed an store app it works fine when we deployed in domain2 it not working.As it throwing an error we fixed that error in the domain2 and installed in the domain1 it doesn't work but it working fine in domain2.

I tried using

```
string dnsName = await Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetDomainNameAsync();
```

but it returning empty string

for eg, I'm having two domains like Dev and Test,my need is to get the name as Dev and Test.

any solution or code is provided is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of this requires the Enterprise Authentication capability, which in turn requires a business account (not an individual developer account) on the Windows Store. All that's possible to do of course.

I'd thought the result would be blank if Enterprise Authentication were not checked. The documentation says that [GetDomainNameAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getdomainnameasync) does not throw an exception, but I'm definitely seeing a UnauthorizedAccessException in that case.

So presuming that is not the issue, note you will get an empty string on that call if the user turned off the sharing of that information via PC Setttings:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply i checked out all the solutions provided but still i'm not getting the domain name, i'm getting the username when i tried giving GetDisplayNameAsync().Is there any other way to get the domain name of the system.

Comment: is the user logged in with a domain account?

Comment: yes, because it's getting the domain name for the user, note it's a method on the [UserInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241871.aspx) class.  I'm not on a domain joined machine but I wonder if [GetHostNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.gethostnames.aspx) or some other method in [Windows.Networking.Connectivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212028.aspx) would help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it worked "var dns= Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();" i'm able to get the dns name.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For getting Domain name for user you have to use

```
string dnsName = Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetDomainNameAsync();
```

Click Here for [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getdomainnameasync),Here is the User domain name sample on [MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/User-domain-name-sample-85ce3e49).

Comment: thanks for reply, i previously tried it but it returning me "System.__ComObject". I'm unable to get the domain name.

Comment: @JimO'Neil kept await but it returns empty to string.